# MongooseJS - How to specify a field of an object in an array of a document in Mongoose Populate Virtuals?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following document

```
{
  name: "Johnny Doe",
  age: "55",
  organizations: [
  {name: "Org A",
   members: 22
  },
  {name: "Org B",
   members: 25
  }]
}
```

And lets say I have a virtual set up for another schema

```
SomeSchema.virtual('organizations'){
 ref:"Person", //the collection to reference
 localField:"organization_name",  //the field in this Schema
 foreignField: [???]  //I want to access Person.organizations[].name
}
```

How do I specify the field I want in localField/foreignField? I have tried "organizations.$.name" like in MongoDB but it doesn't work, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Just use `field_array.field_of_array_object` or in my example `organizations.name`. It doesn't matter if its in an array, just use the `.` notation.